# In C# the process exits immediately

Tags: c#, process, exit, cplex, exit-code

I have 3 codes(programs). These are p1, p2, p3. p1 and p2 are subprograms. p3 is main program that calls them. I published p1.exe and p2.exe. Then in p3 code, I run p1.exe and p2.exe using Process(). It works, but I moved my codes to another computer, it does not work. In p3 code, I run p1.exe and p2.exe using Process() as same method. p1.exe works, p2.exe works independently, but in p3 code, p1.exe and p2.exe closes immediately, then p3 code continues to next code. What can be the problem? I tried using same Visual Studio, same operating system. p1 and p2 codes has IBM Cplex library, has connection a dll file about Cplex. Is that problem about Cplex?

p1 -> program that runs cplex model.

p2 -> program that runs another cplex model.

p1.exe works independently. It takes about 5 minutes.

p2.exe works independently. It takes about 5 minutes.

p3(main program) -> calls p1.exe and p2.exe but cplex inside them doesn't work.
code sample:

```
Process firstProc = new Process();
firstProc.StartInfo.FileName = this.t1_program; // p1.exe url
firstProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
firstProc.Start();
firstProc.WaitForExit();
Console.Out.WriteLine(firstProc.ExitCode);
```

This code gives output -1073741819 as exitcode. Normally it should take about 5 minutes but it finishes in 1 second.
normally I worked in Visual Studio 2017. 
For this in Visual Studio 2019 I also got the same error with explanation:

```
Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at ILOG.OPL.opl_lang_wrapPINVOKE.OplModel_getOuterModel(IntPtr)
   at ILOG.OPL.opl_lang_wrapPINVOKE.OplModel_getOuterModel(IntPtr)
   at ILOG.OPL.OplModel.getOuterModel()
   at ILOG.OPL.OplModel.generate()
   at ILOG.OPL.OplModel.Generate()
   at T1_Cplex.Program.Main(System.String[])
-1073741819
```

Windows Event Viewer says:

```
T1_Hatti.exe 
   1.0.0.0 
   5e597f86 
   coreclr.dll 
   4.700.20.11803 
   5e4c6185 
   c0000005 
   0000000000191809 
   297c 
   01d620d5ec616a74 
   C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\T1_Hatti\T1_Hatti\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\T1_Hatti.exe 
   C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.3\coreclr.dll 
   4572ab00-e71f-4eea-9cfc-e198ef3bc9f9 

Application: T1_Hatti.exe CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.11803 .NET Core Version: 3.1.3 Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFF2BD11809 (00007FFF2BB80000) with exit code c0000005.
```

Comment: Capture the stdout/stderr for diagnosis? Must these programs be attached to terminals?

Comment: Have happens when you run these sub-programs in a Command Prompt/shell outside of p3? Maybe you've missed copying over some dependencies (DLLs) your programs require

Comment: @nijave I tried to run the subprograms from cmd. They worked. They have dll file.

Comment: @user2864740 yes, they are terminal programs.

Comment: Did you look into Windows event viewer?

Comment: @RandRandom I added Windows Event Viewer output to question.

Comment: I tried "mspaint.exe", "notepad.exe" to test, they work.

Comment: Set the `WorkingDirectory`. If the calling process is not .Net Core, `UseShellExecute` is `true` by default. `EnableRaisingEvents = true` is only used to raise the `Exited` event. If these programs need command line arguments, use the `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` property, do not add them to the executable FileName.

Comment: @Jimi It worked!!! Thank you very much. WorkingDirectory solved the problem. Thank you for everyone that commented.

Comment: Should I edit the question? Should I write the solution to the question now?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with adding WorkingDirectory.